# Swapping array elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this - (i do not know the length of this array in advance)

```
data: [[3, 1], [1, 1], [5, 1], [6, 1], [25, 1], [8, 2], [2, 3]]
```

how i can swap it so it becomes like this:

```
data: [[1, 3], [1, 1], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 25], [2, 8], [3, 2]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Smells like homework. If it is, please tag it as such.

Comment: wish it was! ..i will accept Xander's very quick answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each element is an array, so you can apply reverse on it.

```
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) data[i].reverse();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var i, temp;

for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    temp = data[i][0];

    data[i][0] = data[i][1];
    data[i][1] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [[3, 1], [1, 1], [5, 1], [6, 1], [25, 1], [8, 2], [2, 3]];
data = data.map(function(x){ // loop though all elements
    return x.reverse(); // reverse each array
});
```

[`Arary.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) should work on all modern browsers (by that I mean you need Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, or IE9+).

EDIT: Since [`Array.reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) will mutate the array, you can also do this:

```
var data = [[3, 1], [1, 1], [5, 1], [6, 1], [25, 1], [8, 2], [2, 3]];
data.forEach(function(x){ // loop though all elements
    x.reverse(); // reverse each array
});
```

[`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) works in the same "moden" browsers, that `.map` works in.

Comment: It seems that `.forEach` is much slower than a normal `for` loop